# Stochastic thermodynamic reference

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, stochastic-processes

I am looking for a nice reference of stochastic thermodynamic for physicists (I have found some book of it but very mathematical with theory of measure for example).

The info I need are proper definitions: how do we define properly trajectories, how do we find the second principle etc.

I am looking for a book explaining properly and rigorously the basis more than a book very exhaustive on all the aspects of the theory.

Comment: Probably the standard theoretical reference for stochastic thermodynamics is [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4176) by Udo Seifert. I would recommend also reading some of the original papers, such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503686), also by Seifert, and [this one](https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTPS.130.17/1842313) by Sekimoto. There aren't a whole bunch of books or comprehensive references to my knowledge, so it's difficult to give a proper answer given the resource-recommendation tag.

Comment: @MarkMitchison thank you for your answer. The review was fine. But to understand : is stochastic thermodynamic a "new" domain ? Because I find it strange that there are not that many resources about it.

Comment: Well, it depends what you consider to be the "start" of the field. The [Jarzynski equality](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.78.2690) is 21 years old. [Seifert's framework](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.95.040602) with trajectory entropies etc. is more like 13 years old. Either way, I would describe it as a very young field indeed. But I should emphasise that I am just not old enough to claim an accurate historical perspective.